# how to check if text in textbox is the text you want(php/html)

Tags: php, html, textbox

i trying to make a game, and you get a couple of letters and you can make a word out of it. there is a textbox below the letters and i want to check if the answer matches one of my words(they are in a array). it dousnt have to be specific that word, if it is one of the words out of the array its good.

here is my code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="nl">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Maak een woord uit de gehusselde letters:</h3>

        <?php
            $antwoorden = array("woorden","patat","laptop","telefoon","bureau","plafond");
            $hussel = array("dowrneo","tptaa","paplot","oefletno","uaebru","faldnop");
            /* gehusselde letters hier(array??)*/

            echo $hussel[array_rand($hussel)];
        ?>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Antwoord" name="antwoord">
        <button 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I am not planning to do it for you, but i will help you a little, `ajax request` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ , to send user entered word to a `php` file which contains array of possible words, where you can easily check with `in_array()` php function and echo value which will say he got the right word. The value you echoed will be backed to `ajax`, just check `ajax requests`.

Comment: We have something that is called `in_array`, that might solve your problem Here is the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) about it. Here is an intro to [`Ajax`](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) as you will need that for you application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks every one for answering, it is working the way i want now. this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Maak een woord uit de gehusselde letters:</h3>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
    <?php
        $antwoorden = array("woorden", "patat", "laptop", "telefoon", "bureau", "plafond");
        $hussel = array("dowrneo","tptaa","paplot","oefletno","uaebru","faldnop");
        /* gehusselde letters hier(array??)*/

        $gehuseld = $hussel[array_rand($hussel)];
        echo $gehuseld
    ?>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Antwoord" name="antwoord">
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Controleren</button>
    </form>

    <?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        if (in_array($_POST['antwoord'],$antwoorden))
        {
            echo "Correct!<br>";
        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo "Probeer het nog een keer.<br>";
        }           
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

what this code dous is=
there are words in one array and the same words but scrambled in another.
the code displays one scrambled word and the person behind the laptop has to type the word you can make with that letters. when he presses the submit button there will be lookt if his answer is the same as one of the words in the good array. when there is one word the same it will say: correct!
when its not the same it will say: try again(in dutch).

thanks for helping all!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to to that in PHP as well.  This is the link for the in_array() function: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Do you check it once they are done typing or do they fit a button of some sort?  If you have a button, which it looks like you do (I cannot read the instructions) then that should be easy enough.  If you need to detect when the value of the box changes, i could explain that too.

Comment: hi J Seaton, thanks for your answer. i lookt at it and i think i'm gonna use this peace of code:                                                                           if (in_array("woorden","patat","laptop","telefoon","bureau","plafond", $antwoorden, TRUE))
  {
  echo "Match found<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found<br>";
  }                                                                                                                   i dont know if it wil work, and where do i put it?

Comment: I think i need a bit more information about what you are trying to do.  It is my understanding that you will print out all the words in one array and ask them to make a word.  When they input their word, which could be any unscrambled word from the first array, you want to see if that array is in the second array.  Is that correct? If so, you would use the function like so: in_array("usersInput", $antwoorden).  I don't see above how you are getting the user input.  If you are just checking to see if the value in the textbox changed, then you need javascript or some sort of client side script.